# Gentoo virt-manager IO throttling

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, io, qemu, gentoo

I have a problem with virt-manager (or qemu/libvirt) installed on gentoo.

Here is My virt-manager installed on Debian Jessie:

[image]

There I have IO throttling but not on my Gentoo:

[image]

I tried to search in google but I have not found nothing helpful on gentoo.

Everyone know what else I need to do to have this option?

My kernel:

```
cat /usr/src/linux/.config | grep CGROUP
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_BLK_CGROUP is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_WRITEBACK=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_CLASSID=y
```

My mounts:

```
mount | grep cgroup
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup(rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/debug type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,debug)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
```

And My use flags for packages:

```
emerge -pv virt-manager

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-emulation/virt-manager-1.3.2::gentoo  USE="gnome-keyring gtk policykit -debug -sasl" LINGUAS="pl -as -bg -bn_IN -bs -ca -cmn -cs -da -de -en_GB -es -fi -fr -gu -hi -hr -hu -is -it -ja -kn -ko -ml -mr -ms -nb -nl -or -pa -pt -pt_BR -ro -ru -sk -sr -sr@latin -sv -ta -te -tr -uk -vi -zh_CN -zh_TW" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 0 KiB


emerge -pv qemu

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-emulation/qemu-2.5.1::gentoo  USE="aio alsa bluetooth caps curl fdt filecaps gtk jpeg lzo ncurses nls opengl pin-upstream-blobs png pulseaudio python sdl seccomp spice ssh threads usb usbredir uuid vhost-net vnc xattr -accessibility -debug (-glusterfs) -gnutls -gtk2 -infiniband -iscsi -nfs -numa -rbd -sasl -sdl2 (-selinux) -smartcard -snappy -static -static-softmmu -static-user -systemtap -tci {-test} -vde -virgl -virtfs -vte -xen -xfs" LINGUAS="-de_DE -fr_FR -hu -it -tr -zh_CN" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" QEMU_SOFTMMU_TARGETS="x86_64 -aarch64 -alpha -arm -cris -i386 -lm32 -m68k -microblaze -microblazeel -mips -mips64 -mips64el -mipsel -moxie -or32 -ppc -ppc64 -ppcemb -s390x -sh4 -sh4eb -sparc -sparc64 -tricore -unicore32 -xtensa -xtensaeb" QEMU_USER_TARGETS="-aarch64 -alpha -arm -armeb -cris -i386 -m68k -microblaze -microblazeel -mips -mips64 -mips64el -mipsel -mipsn32 -mipsn32el -or32 -ppc -ppc64 -ppc64abi32 -ppc64le -s390x -sh4 -sh4eb -sparc -sparc32plus -sparc64 -tilegx -unicore32 -x86_64" 0 KiB


emerge -pv libvirt

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-emulation/libvirt-1.3.1-r1:0/1.3.1::gentoo  USE="caps libvirtd macvtap nls policykit qemu systemd udev vepa virt-network (-apparmor) -audit -avahi -firewalld -fuse (-glusterfs) -iscsi -lvm -lxc -nfs -numa -openvz -parted -pcap -phyp -rbd -sasl (-selinux) -uml -virtualbox (-wireshark-plugins) -xen" 0 KiB
```